# Holomorphic vs Analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the function $2 \bar{Z}$ is holomorphic? I understand that holomorphic means that the function is differentiable. How is that different from being analytic?

Comment: 1 - It's not 2 - A priori they're wildly different, then we are amazed to discover that actually there's no difference. But a quick look at the wikipedia page would clear up your doubts, so I suggest you look there before asking a question here and if you still have doubts specify what exactly you don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually we can prove that the following concepts are equivalent :

- Holomorphy (cancellation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$)
- $\mathbb{C}$-differenciability.
- Analyticity (power series expansion).

For exemple, you can check that $$\frac{\partial (2\overline{z})}{\partial \overline{z}} =2 \neq 0$$ hence it is not holomorphic.

Comment: how do you define $\displaystyle \frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}$? I've never seen that :)

Comment: The definition is $$\displaystyle \frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}=\frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right )$$ :)